# vue-router same route with different param

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am on the `/entries/12` route. On the same component I would like to push `/entries/13` when user clicks the next button.

Code is like :

```
//e is the next page number. 
 this.$router.push({ name: 'Entries', params: { pageNum: e }});
```

I get below error:

[image]

If i try different route that works.

Whole code:

```
<template>


    <div class="entries">

        <generic-entries @clicked="clicked" ></generic-entries>

    </div>

</template>

<script>
    import GenericEntriesComp from '@/components/GenericEntriesComp';

    export default{
        name: 'entries-comp',

        components: {genericEntries: GenericEntriesComp},
        mounted(){
            var params = {id : this.$route.params.pageNum}
            this.$store.dispatch("getEntries",params);
        },
        methods: {

            clicked(e){

                this.$router.push({ name: 'Entries', params: { pageNum: e.toString() }});

            },
            loadData(){
                var params = {pageNum : this.$route.params.pageNum}
                this.$store.dispatch("getEntries", params)
            }
        },
        computed: {
            items(){
                return this.$store.state.entries
            },
        },
        watch: {
            '$route': 'loadData'
        }
    }


</script>
```

Btw the error comes from :

```
Vue.config.errorHandler = function (err, vm, info) {
    console.error(err);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that code responsible for that route is correct and valid ? What happens when you manually go to the `entry/13` ?

Comment: Should work if your routes object contains the following route: { path: '/entry/:pageNum', name: 'Entries' } . Is that the structure you're using?

Comment: @BelminBedak If i try different named route it works. So, I believe it is.

Comment: @Joos, I updated my question, yes, my definition is correct.

Comment: Could it be because e is a number and not a String, and the router doesn't know how to handle it? Just guessing at this point :P

Comment: If you have a watcher setup for `$route` can you show it

Comment: @VamsiKrishna I put my whole code. Please see above.

Comment: @Joos I thought of it :) no luck

Answer (score 44):

I solved my problem with `:key`. This way, I guarantee that all router-view content will be re-rendered whenever there is a $route change.

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath" @showLoading="showLoading"></router-view>
```

Answer (score 5):

Found the answer.

Seems `vue-router` works as expected. In my case there were another problem.

If I have below code also in generic component I beleive it loops and produce an error.

```
watch: {
        '$route': function(){
            this.loadData();
        }
    }
```

In my case I removed the watcher from the generic component and it worked.

Comment: Awesome solution, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have decided to change the route parameter programmatically, then you should use `replace` instead of `push` as like below:

```
//e is the next page number. 
this.$router.replace({ name: 'Entries', params: { pageNum: e }});
```